# How can i get food name and nutrition name and value from thousand of record like this using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[{"meal": "MY food", "dishes": [{"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "412"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "29"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "24"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "21"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "258"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "29"}], "name": "my - McDonalds Espresso Pronto\u00ae Flat White, 2 TALL"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "170"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "25"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "5"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "20"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "260"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "2"}], "name": "Quest Bar - Banana Nut Muffin Natural Protein Bar, 60 g"}, {"nutritions": [{"name": "Calories", "value": "176"}, {"name": "Carbs", "value": "33"}, {"name": "Fat", "value": "1"}, {"name": "Protein", "value": "5"}, {"name": "Sodium", "value": "195"}, {"name": "Sugar", "value": "0"}]

| Food | Calories | Carbs | Fat | Protein | Sodium | Sugar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ..Flat White, 2 TALL | 170 | 25 | 5 | 20 | 260 | 2 |
| ..Protein Bar, 60 g | 176 | 33 | 1 | 5 | 195 | 0 |

Comment: Please provide more details about what you want to do exactly, I'm not sure to completely understand your approach.

Comment: My data look like what I posted I want to clean the data and get the food name and his nutrition. That is huge and very complex data in thousands of records of different and same. So it is very difficult to understand. I want data that looks like the table above.

Comment: It looks like JSON to me, so maybe start with the JSON module https://pymotw.com/3/json/index.html And if you are just starting this project you shouldn't be using Python 2.7 so remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

As the data structure suggests, the data are in JSON format. One possibility is to directly read the data into an object using `JSON` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```py
# use module JSON
import json

# let's suppose the data are saved in this file
filename = "data.json"

# open the file and load the data
with open(filename) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# print out the data
for row in data[0]['dishes']:  # note: the '0' is here because of the particular data structure of these data
  print("Name: ", row['name'])
  for nutrition in row['nutritions']:
    print(nutrition['name'], ":", nutrition['value'])
```

Prints out:

```
Name:  my - McDonalds Espresso Pronto® Flat White, 2 TALL
Calories : 412
Carbs : 29
Fat : 24
Protein : 21
Sodium : 258
Sugar : 29
Name:  Quest Bar - Banana Nut Muffin Natural Protein Bar, 60 g
Calories : 170
Carbs : 25
Fat : 5
Protein : 20
Sodium : 260
Sugar : 2
```